# BizTalk custom pipeline component - Inconsistent Message behavior

Tags: c#, biztalk

I have custom pipeline components at both receive and send ports. Messages are polled every 30 sec from WCF-SQL adapter in receive location. The custom receive pipeline component does property promotion for few fields. The send port subscribes above message and does some processing in custom pipeline component. I am monitoring both custom pipeline component activity details like process start and process end by writing the information to event viewer from custom pipeline component code.

I am facing inconsistent behavior while processing the different messages in BizTalk send pipeline. For example, if the receive locations polls 3 different messages (message1, message2, message3) from database. message3 takes longer time to process when compared to message1 and message2.

Sometimes message1, message2 are processed and the service instance shows as completed for these 2 messages with their end time while messages 3 is still in the process. But here comes the issue which is not consistent in behavior, Message1 and message2 service instance still shows active though they are processed in send pipeline and the status of these 2 messages gets updated to completed ONLY after the processing of message3 is completed and end time of all the 3 messages are updated with same message3 service instance end time.

I have debugged both components individually with various breakpoints. I assume that sometimes receive pipeline component is not disassembling or not processing the messages in default parallel delivery mode.

Any inputs to handle this?

Comment: Have you tried putting a trace at your SQL server?  I would look for some blocking/locking behavior. For instance, if Message 3 is locking a table/page/row which prevents message1 & 2 from completing, it might explain this behavior, maybe.

Comment: Same question on Technet https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2ee23adc-4f8e-4d40-8433-9d21cf7dae4f/inconsistent-message-behavior-with-custom-pipeline-components?forum=biztalkgeneral